# Pre and post Flag column on specific service and its date time

Tags: r, sorting, group-by

I am trying to create a flag of pre and post based on the specific service 'Bedday-HTHC' and its date time.
The outcome will be in the column 'flag'.
This way, I will be able to report pre-hthc and post-hthc costs.

The key here is the ordering of the ordering of the DayOfStay in ascending.

Context = 'better at home' is a new healthcare model by discharging patients earlier to their own home for saving hospital beds and patient convenience

Now, I am doing evaluation of the program by looking it the financial impact.

I hope you will help me in this important endeavour.

Thank you very much.

```
hthc <- tibble::tribble(
                 ~id,                          ~area,                  ~service, ~Quantity, ~DayOfStay,     ~StartDateTime,       ~EndDateTime, ~Total.Cost,       ~flag,
          "patient1",                    "A0160_CCU",              "Bedday-CCU",   9.18333,         1L,  "24/04/2022 0:00",  "24/04/2022 9:10", 1366.438369,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",         "A4402_CardiacSurgery",           "Med Days-CSUR",        60,         1L,  "24/04/2022 0:00", "24/04/2022 23:59", 647.2966689,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",     "P0052_Chaplaincy Service",              "Chaplaincy",         1,         1L,  "24/04/2022 0:00", "24/04/2022 23:59", 1.872038507,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",               "R0155_Catering",                  "CATRG-",         1,         1L,  "24/04/2022 0:00", "24/04/2022 23:59", 46.76093351,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",            "A0903_Ward 5 East",               "Bedday-5E",  14.81667,         1L,  "24/04/2022 9:11", "24/04/2022 23:59", 16.83546044,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0002_Pharmacy_S&W",                "Pharm_SW",         3,         1L, "24/04/2022 10:16", "24/04/2022 10:16", 53.34547284,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0002_Pharmacy_S&W",                "Pharm_SW",         8,         1L, "24/04/2022 10:16", "24/04/2022 10:16", 53.34547284,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",               "N0502_Pharmacy",                 "Pharm-N",         3,         1L, "24/04/2022 10:16", "24/04/2022 10:16", 2.363352182,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",               "N0502_Pharmacy",                 "Pharm-N",         8,         1L, "24/04/2022 10:16", "24/04/2022 10:16", 1.010536795,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",            "A0903_Ward 5 East",               "Bedday-5E",        24,         2L,  "25/04/2022 0:00", "25/04/2022 23:59", 27.27003102,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",         "A4402_CardiacSurgery",           "Med Days-CSUR",        60,         2L,  "25/04/2022 0:00", "25/04/2022 23:59", 647.2966689,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",     "P0052_Chaplaincy Service",              "Chaplaincy",         1,         2L,  "25/04/2022 0:00", "25/04/2022 23:59", 1.872038507,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",               "R0155_Catering",                  "CATRG-",         1,         2L,  "25/04/2022 0:00", "25/04/2022 23:59", 46.76093351,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",      "Y0252_Path_Biochemistry",        "Path-Y0252-66500",         1,         2L,  "25/04/2022 0:00",  "25/04/2022 0:00", 2.881859708,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",      "Y0252_Path_Biochemistry",        "Path-Y0252-66512",         1,         2L,  "25/04/2022 0:00",  "25/04/2022 0:00", 5.250511523,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",       "Y0352_Path_Haemotology",        "Path-Y0352-65070",         1,         2L,  "25/04/2022 0:00",  "25/04/2022 0:00", 14.07869458,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",       "Y0352_Path_Haemotology",        "Path-Y0352-65120",         1,         2L,  "25/04/2022 0:00",  "25/04/2022 0:00", 11.37337679,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",     "Y1106_Imaging Department",   "IMG-R.XRCHEST.AER2.NH",         1,         2L, "25/04/2022 15:33", "25/04/2022 15:33", 84.73569345,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",            "A0903_Ward 5 East",               "Bedday-5E",        24,         3L,  "26/04/2022 0:00", "26/04/2022 23:59", 27.27003102,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",         "A4402_CardiacSurgery",           "Med Days-CSUR",        60,         3L,  "26/04/2022 0:00", "26/04/2022 23:59", 647.2966689,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",     "P0052_Chaplaincy Service",              "Chaplaincy",         1,         3L,  "26/04/2022 0:00", "26/04/2022 23:59", 1.872038507,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",               "R0155_Catering",                  "CATRG-",         1,         3L,  "26/04/2022 0:00", "26/04/2022 23:59", 46.76093351,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",      "Y0252_Path_Biochemistry",        "Path-Y0252-66500",         1,         3L,  "26/04/2022 0:00",  "26/04/2022 0:00", 2.881859708,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",      "Y0252_Path_Biochemistry",        "Path-Y0252-66512",         1,         3L,  "26/04/2022 0:00",  "26/04/2022 0:00", 5.250511523,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",       "Y0352_Path_Haemotology",        "Path-Y0352-65070",         1,         3L,  "26/04/2022 0:00",  "26/04/2022 0:00", 14.07869458,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",                     "N2702_OT",                   "OCCUP",         1,         3L,  "26/04/2022 9:31",  "26/04/2022 9:31", 231.3588805,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",                     "N2702_OT",                   "OCCUP",         1,         3L, "26/04/2022 10:05", "26/04/2022 10:05", 231.3588805,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N2602_Interpreters", "Interpreter-interpreter",         1,         3L, "26/04/2022 13:37", "26/04/2022 14:22", 128.6254261,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",            "A0903_Ward 5 East",               "Bedday-5E",  14.03333,         4L,  "27/04/2022 0:00", "27/04/2022 14:01", 15.94538935,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",         "A4402_CardiacSurgery",           "Med Days-CSUR",        60,         4L,  "27/04/2022 0:00", "27/04/2022 23:59", 647.2966689,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",     "P0052_Chaplaincy Service",              "Chaplaincy",         1,         4L,  "27/04/2022 0:00", "27/04/2022 23:59", 1.872038507,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",               "R0155_Catering",                  "CATRG-",         1,         4L,  "27/04/2022 0:00", "27/04/2022 23:59", 46.76093351,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",      "Y0252_Path_Biochemistry",        "Path-Y0252-66500",         1,         4L,  "27/04/2022 0:00",  "27/04/2022 0:00", 2.881859708,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",      "Y0252_Path_Biochemistry",        "Path-Y0252-66512",         1,         4L,  "27/04/2022 0:00",  "27/04/2022 0:00", 5.250511523,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",       "Y0352_Path_Haemotology",        "Path-Y0352-65070",         1,         4L,  "27/04/2022 0:00",  "27/04/2022 0:00", 14.07869458,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0002_Pharmacy_S&W",                "Pharm_SW",         4,         4L,  "27/04/2022 8:31",  "27/04/2022 8:31", 53.34547284,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",               "N0502_Pharmacy",                 "Pharm-N",         4,         4L,  "27/04/2022 8:31",  "27/04/2022 8:31", 1.108330678,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",     "Y1106_Imaging Department",   "IMG-R.XRCHEST.AER1.NH",         1,         4L,  "27/04/2022 9:52",  "27/04/2022 9:52", 84.73569345,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0002_Pharmacy_S&W",                "Pharm_SW",         1,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 53.34547284,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0002_Pharmacy_S&W",                "Pharm_SW",         1,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 53.34547284,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0002_Pharmacy_S&W",                "Pharm_SW",         7,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 53.34547284,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0002_Pharmacy_S&W",                "Pharm_SW",        30,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 53.34547284,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0002_Pharmacy_S&W",                "Pharm_SW",        30,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 53.34547284,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0002_Pharmacy_S&W",                "Pharm_SW",        30,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 53.34547284,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0002_Pharmacy_S&W",                "Pharm_SW",       100,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 53.34547284,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",               "N0502_Pharmacy",                 "Pharm-N",         1,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47",  6.06322077,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",               "N0502_Pharmacy",                 "Pharm-N",        30,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 2.265558298,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",               "N0502_Pharmacy",                 "Pharm-N",        30,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 2.656733832,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",               "N0502_Pharmacy",                 "Pharm-N",        30,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 5.655746256,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0896_Pharmacy PBS",                 "Pharm-Y",         1,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 309.1159459,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0896_Pharmacy PBS",                 "Pharm-Y",         7,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 0.125355775,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0896_Pharmacy PBS",                 "Pharm-Y",       100,         4L, "27/04/2022 10:47", "27/04/2022 10:47", 1.720792916,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0002_Pharmacy_S&W",                "Pharm_SW",        28,         4L, "27/04/2022 12:08", "27/04/2022 12:08", 53.34547284,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N0896_Pharmacy PBS",                 "Pharm-Y",        28,         4L, "27/04/2022 12:08", "27/04/2022 12:08", 7.954393743,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1",           "N2602_Interpreters", "Interpreter-interpreter",         1,         4L, "27/04/2022 12:46", "27/04/2022 13:31", 128.6254261,  "pre_hthc",
          "patient1", "F0423_Better_at_home_cardiac",             "Bedday-HTHC",   9.96667,         4L, "27/04/2022 14:02", "27/04/2022 23:59", 344.3686508, "post_hthc",
          "patient1",         "A4402_CardiacSurgery",           "Med Days-CSUR",        60,         5L,  "28/04/2022 0:00", "28/04/2022 23:59", 647.2966689, "post_hthc",
          "patient1", "F0423_Better_at_home_cardiac",             "Bedday-HTHC",        24,         5L,  "28/04/2022 0:00", "28/04/2022 23:59", 829.2486477, "post_hthc",
          "patient1",     "P0052_Chaplaincy Service",              "Chaplaincy",         1,         5L,  "28/04/2022 0:00", "28/04/2022 23:59", 1.872038507, "post_hthc",
          "patient1",               "R0155_Catering",                  "CATRG-",         1,         5L,  "28/04/2022 0:00", "28/04/2022 23:59", 46.76093351, "post_hthc",
          "patient1",         "A4402_CardiacSurgery",           "Med Days-CSUR",        60,         6L,  "29/04/2022 0:00", "29/04/2022 14:00", 647.2966689, "post_hthc",
          "patient1", "F0423_Better_at_home_cardiac",             "Bedday-HTHC",        14,         6L,  "29/04/2022 0:00", "29/04/2022 14:00", 483.7283779, "post_hthc",
          "patient1",     "P0052_Chaplaincy Service",              "Chaplaincy",         1,         6L,  "29/04/2022 0:00", "29/04/2022 14:00", 1.872038507, "post_hthc",
          "patient1",               "R0155_Catering",                  "CATRG-",         1,         6L,  "29/04/2022 0:00", "29/04/2022 14:00", 46.76093351, "post_hthc"
          )
hthc
#> # A tibble: 64 × 9
#>    id      area  service Quantity DayOfStay StartDateTime EndDateTime Total.Cost
#>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>     <int> <chr>         <chr>            <dbl>
#>  1 patien… A016… Bedday…     9.18         1 24/04/2022 0… 24/04/2022…    1366.  
#>  2 patien… A440… Med Da…    60            1 24/04/2022 0… 24/04/2022…     647.  
#>  3 patien… P005… Chapla…     1            1 24/04/2022 0… 24/04/2022…       1.87
#>  4 patien… R015… CATRG-      1            1 24/04/2022 0… 24/04/2022…      46.8 
#>  5 patien… A090… Bedday…    14.8          1 24/04/2022 9… 24/04/2022…      16.8 
#>  6 patien… N000… Pharm_…     3            1 24/04/2022 1… 24/04/2022…      53.3 
#>  7 patien… N000… Pharm_…     8            1 24/04/2022 1… 24/04/2022…      53.3 
#>  8 patien… N050… Pharm-N     3            1 24/04/2022 1… 24/04/2022…       2.36
#>  9 patien… N050… Pharm-N     8            1 24/04/2022 1… 24/04/2022…       1.01
#> 10 patien… A090… Bedday…    24            2 25/04/2022 0… 25/04/2022…      27.3 
#> # ℹ 54 more rows
#> # ℹ 1 more variable: flag <chr>

library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

hthc$StartDateTime <- dmy_hm(hthc$StartDateTime)

hthc$EndDateTime <- dmy_hm(hthc$EndDateTime)

hthc
#> # A tibble: 64 × 9
#>    id       area                  service Quantity DayOfStay StartDateTime      
#>    <chr>    <chr>                 <chr>      <dbl>     <int> <dttm>             
#>  1 patient1 A0160_CCU             Bedday…     9.18         1 2022-04-24 00:00:00
#>  2 patient1 A4402_CardiacSurgery  Med Da…    60            1 2022-04-24 00:00:00
#>  3 patient1 P0052_Chaplaincy Ser… Chapla…     1            1 2022-04-24 00:00:00
#>  4 patient1 R0155_Catering        CATRG-      1            1 2022-04-24 00:00:00
#>  5 patient1 A0903_Ward 5 East     Bedday…    14.8          1 2022-04-24 09:11:00
#>  6 patient1 N0002_Pharmacy_S&W    Pharm_…     3            1 2022-04-24 10:16:00
#>  7 patient1 N0002_Pharmacy_S&W    Pharm_…     8            1 2022-04-24 10:16:00
#>  8 patient1 N0502_Pharmacy        Pharm-N     3            1 2022-04-24 10:16:00
#>  9 patient1 N0502_Pharmacy        Pharm-N     8            1 2022-04-24 10:16:00
#> 10 patient1 A0903_Ward 5 East     Bedday…    24            2 2022-04-25 00:00:00
#> # ℹ 54 more rows
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: EndDateTime <dttm>, Total.Cost <dbl>, flag <chr>

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

hthc %>% 
  group_by(flag) %>% 
  summarise(cost = sum(Total.Cost))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   flag       cost
#>   <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 post_hthc 3049.
#> 2 pre_hthc  6132.
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My research question is whether post-hthc cost < pre-hthc cost or not.  Then we could make decisions on moving patients earlier to hthc better at home program, then we could make more hospital beds available for treating the urgently needed.  Thank you.

Comment: I understand your research question. What is your programming question? Where is the problem in your code? Why does it not do what you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained clearer.  How can I create a flag column (as in the last column), which will tell the period before and after time the service column having the 'first' Bedday-HTHC 27/04/2022 14:02?  Before  that first datetime is 'pre-' and after 'post-'.  Thank you.

Comment: But you already have a `flag` column.  Are you saying that the data frame you've posted is your desired output?  If so, what is the input that should lead to that output?  The same data frame without the `flag` column?  Something else?  What have you tried and why didn't it work?  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: My desired output is the flag column, which is currently constructed manually.  Input dataframe is the same without the flag column.  The codes above was created with repex v2.0.2.  Thank you

Comment: The above example is for a patient only.  I have hundreds of patients to analyse.  The manual construction is hard when n > 1.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several records in your test data start after the start time of your baseline (Bedday_HTHC) and finish on or before the end time of your baseline.  These appear to be handled inconsistently in your output or - at least, I haven't been able to figure out the algorithm you've used.  Nonetheless, this should get you headed in the right direction.  You should be able to modify what I've given you to give the result you want based on knowledge you have but I don't.

The fact that you have more than one patient does not add great complexity to the problem.

Create the input data

```
library(tidyverse)

inputData <- hthc %>% select(-flag)
```

Obtain the baseline of reference date for each patient:

```
> firstHTHC <- inputData %>% 
+   group_by(id) %>% 
+   filter(service == "Bedday-HTHC") %>%  
+   head(1) %>%  select(id, EndDateTime) %>% 
+   rename(FirstHTHCTime = EndDateTime) %>% 
+   ungroup()
> firstHTHC
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  id       FirstHTHCTime   
  <chr>    <chr>           
1 patient1 27/04/2022 23:59
```

Now merge this information with the input data frame and determine whether each record is "pre" or "post" baseline.  As I've already said, the fact that your records all refer to periods rather than instants of time make the definition of "pre" and "post" slightly ambiguous.

```
outputData <- hthc %>% 
  left_join(firstHTHC, by = "id") %>% 
  mutate(new_flag = ifelse(FirstHTHCTime >= EndDateTime, "pre_hthc", "post_hthc"))
```

Now check for differences:

```
outputData%>% filter(flag!= new_flag)
# A tibble: 4 × 11
  id       area                         service               Quantity DayOfStay StartDateTime    EndDateTime      Total.Cost flag      FirstHTHCTime    new_flag 
  <chr>    <chr>                        <chr>                    <dbl>     <int> <chr>            <chr>                 <dbl> <chr>     <chr>            <chr>    
1 patient1 N0002_Pharmacy_S&W           Pharm_SW                  4            4 27/04/2022 8:31  27/04/2022 8:31       53.3  pre_hthc  27/04/2022 23:59 post_hthc
2 patient1 N0502_Pharmacy               Pharm-N                   4            4 27/04/2022 8:31  27/04/2022 8:31        1.11 pre_hthc  27/04/2022 23:59 post_hthc
3 patient1 Y1106_Imaging Department     IMG-R.XRCHEST.AER1.NH     1            4 27/04/2022 9:52  27/04/2022 9:52       84.7  pre_hthc  27/04/2022 23:59 post_hthc
4 patient1 F0423_Better_at_home_cardiac Bedday-HTHC               9.97         4 27/04/2022 14:02 27/04/2022 23:59     344.   post_hthc 27/04/2022 23:59 pre_hthc
```

If it weren't for the ambiguity in the definitions of "pre" and "post", I would have written the derivation as

```
outputData <- inputData %>% 
  left_join(firstHTHC, by = "id") %>% 
  mutate(flag = ifelse(FirstHTHCTime >= EndDateTime, "pre_hthc", "post_hthc")) %>% 
  select(-FirstHTHCTime)
```

I hope that sets you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your answer solves my problem.  Appreciated for your prompt attention and effort.